# Haskell construct a type contains class

Tags: class, generics, haskell, type-constructor

I want to construct a haskell type:

```
    type SinglePP = (String,GLattice)
```

Where the GLattice is defined as:

```
    class GLattice l where
        join :: l->l->l
        ....
```

Is there a way for me to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
type SinglePP a = (String, a)
```

and then when you use `SinglePP` in a function, restrict `a` to be a `GLattice`

```
someFunc :: GLattice a => SinglePP a -> ()
someFunc a = doMagic a
```

If you like, you can use more type system-foo and go with existential types, which let you avoid the boilerplate after each function, but in exchange you must use a language extension and a `data` declaration with an explicit constructor. This means more pattern matching when you want to get at the `a` but less typing in the type declarations.

However most of the types can be inferred.

Comment: What if I want to represent the SinglePP in a list, e.g. I want to do something like : type ProgramPoints = [SinglePP]

Answer (score 3):

Use the `ExistentialQuantification` extension, like so:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

class GLattice l where
    join :: l -> l -> l

data SinglePP = forall a . (GLattice a) => SinglePP String a
```

This guarantees that the value stored in `SinglePP`'s second field holds a type that implements the `GLattice` class, but does not specify which type.  This means that you will only be able to use the `GLattice` operations on it.

Comment: This seems like a bit too much for someone who seems to have trouble with basic Haskell syntax. Existentials can lead to odd edge cases.

Comment: what about when I want to get the content from SinglePP, e.g. something like getVarFromPP ::(GLattice a)=> SinglePP -> a, its not working if i use a pattern matche